# Can't build with postsharp :(

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, postsharp

I'm using Postsharp 2.1, when I trying to build a project:

C:\Projects\xxx\PostSharp.targets(303,5): error MSB6004: The specified task executable location "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\QGCDWLBB.PR6\E2MK9PKC.00Z\ea4e768b\009e9bf2_be45cd01\postsharp.4.0-x86.exe" is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is because the file PostSharp.MSBuild.*.dll has been installed in GAC, but it should not.